# How to change currenctly selected option with button

Tags: javascript, html

I created two buttons, left and right. For left i want to get previous selected option, for right next to the current one. How can this be done?

For example now i have selected option with id='black' so with right button i would switch to silver id option, or with left to white without, just with buttons. Thank you in advance

```js
bttnRight.addEventListener("click", function() {
  console.log('rigth')
});

bttnLeft.addEventListener("click", function() {
  console.log('left')
});
```

```html
<select id="11" class="select-css">
  <option id="white" value="0"></option>
  <option id="black" value="-5"></option>
  <option id="silver" value="-10"></option>
</select>
```

Comment: So, you want to select options using buttons? Or you're aiming for a carousel and this is just a demo that you provided.

Comment: Yes i want to change options using buttons, without clicking dropdown list

Answer (score 1):

- Add a click listener to both the buttons.
- You can use a single handler and just pass in the amount by which you wish to move, for example on left button click move `-1` step and on right button click move `+1` step.
- Then set the selected index as shown in the snippet below.

```js
const select = document.querySelector("select");
const {options: {length}} = select;

document.getElementById("btn-left").addEventListener("click", () => handleClick(-1));
document.getElementById("btn-right").addEventListener("click", () => handleClick(1));

function handleClick(delta) {
  select.selectedIndex = (select.selectedIndex + length + delta) % length;
}
```

```html
<select>
  <option>One</option>
  <option>Two</option>
  <option>Three</option>
  <option>Four</option>
  <option>Five</option>
</select>

<button id="btn-left">Left</button>
<button id="btn-right">Right</button>
```

Comment: @AndreGTH Please check if this solves your problem, do let me know if you have any issues.

Comment: This is exactly what i needed. Thank you very much!

Comment: @AndreGTH Glad that I could help. Consider accepting this as an answer, if this solved your problem. https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers

Answer (score 1):

First, you should avoid adding `id` attributes to `<option>` elements. Just add the `id` to the `<select>`.

Now, you can add appropriate data attributes to your buttons to target the `<select>` element so that you can cycle through the `options` by updating the `selectedIndex`.

```js
const
  getSelectedText = ({ selectedOptions: [ { text } ] }) => text,
  nav = ({ dataset: { target } }, direction) => {
    const
      select = document.querySelector(target),
      { selectedIndex = 0, options: { length } } = select,
      arrow = direction < 0 ? '<<' : '>>';
    select.selectedIndex = (selectedIndex + length + direction) % length;
    console.log(`Changed selection (${arrow}) to: ${getSelectedText(select)}`);
  },
  navPrev = e => nav(e.target, -1),
  navNext = e => nav(e.target, +1);

document.querySelector('.btn-prev').addEventListener('click', navPrev);
document.querySelector('.btn-next').addEventListener('click', navNext);
```

```html
<select name="color">
  <option value="0">White</option>
  <option value="-5">Black</option>
  <option value="-10">Silver</option>
</select>

<button class="btn-prev" data-target="select[name='color']">Prev</button>
<button class="btn-next" data-target="select[name='color']">Next</button>
```